# Any meant where to locate the using?

Tags: c#, using, binaryreader

WiresharkFile `abstract` class:

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile
{
    private PlayBehavior _playBehavior;

    public void Transmit()
    {
        _playBehavior.Transmit();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        // Implemented inside inherit classes.
    }
}
```

Play options `abstract` class:

```
public abstract class PlayBehavior
{
    public WiresharkFile wiresharkFile;

    public abstract void Transmit();                        
}
```

Play options son class:

```
public class Normal : PlayBehavior
{
    public override void Transmit()
    {
        using (this.wiresharkFile)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So i have this derived class:

```
public class Libpcap : WiresharkFile, IDisposable, IEnumerable<Packet>
{
    private BinaryReader binaryReader;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (binaryReader != null)
            binaryReader.Close();
    }
    ...
    // Severl methods
    ...

    public override void SendPackets()
    {
       base.Transmit();
    }
}
```

My question:

Inside this `Libpcap` class when call `base.Transmit()`: where to use the using ?
Inside this `Libpcap` class SendPackets():

```
public override void SendPackets()
{
   using(this)
   {
      base.Transmit();
   }
}
```

Or inside `Normal` class `Transmit()`:

```
public class Normal : PlayBehavior
{
    public override void Transmit()
    {
        using (this.wiresharkFile)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the literature about the using keyword and when to use it. You use it for object that impletement IDisposable interface.

Comment: My object implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `using(this)` never makes sense. It means you're calling `Dispose` on yourself, which means that A) your class will be at an undefined state at the end of the `using` block, and B) code calling you will see you're `IDisposable` and expect to be able to control your lifetime, but you're actually controlling it yourself from within your code.

If your `Libpcap`'s lifetime ends after the Transmit call, you can use `using` on it from your `PlayBehavior` class - it holds the reference to it, so it controls its lifetime.

Implementing IDisposable is a *contract*. By doing so, you're saying "My operation holds references to unmanaged resources (files, tcp connections, etc), and you, my caller, need to call my `Dispose` method when you're done with me to release them". If this is not the usage contract that WiresharkFile expects, *don't* implement IDisposable.

If you have unmanaged resources that are created and released *as part of your normal* operations, but which doesn't require *your caller* to explicitly release, simply do it yourself - release an *internal* unmanaged resource when you're done with it.

Comment: I implementing IDisposable on WiresharkFile, see my update.

Comment: BTW after this Transmit call my objects is still inside list for future using.

Comment: If you want your WiresharkFile to be usable again, don't dispose it. If you only want the BinaryReader to be disposed after every call, call `using` on *that* object only.

Comment: @davidhol I updated my answer.

Comment: Inside this using i am loop over my file and read the packets, this means that BinaryReader read the bytes. so in this case using this 'using' world inside PlayBehavior is OK ?